# Is this change of variable correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Take the following function:

$$\frac{dn}{d[\log(x)]} = a\exp{\frac{-(\log(x) - b)^2}{c}}$$

I'm interested in obtaining the form for $dn/dx$, so I take:

$$\frac{d[\log(x)]}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow d[\log(x)] = \frac{dx}{x}$$

I use this in the first Eq. to obtain:

$$\frac{dn}{d[\log(x)]} = \frac{dn}{dx} x$$

which  means:

$$\frac{dn}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} a\exp{\frac{-(\log(x) - b)^2}{c}}$$

Is this correct? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Do it simpler $\frac{dn}{dx}=\frac{dn}{d[\log(x)]}\frac{d[\log(x)]}{dx}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{dn}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} a\exp{\frac{-(\log(x) - b)^2}{c}}\ \ $ is correct.

But it doesn't give the solution of the equation $\frac{dn}{d[\log(x)]} = a\exp{\frac{-(\log(x) - b)^2}{c}}$.

Better, change of variable $X=\log(x)$ which leads to $dn = a\exp{\frac{-(X - b)^2}{c}}dX$.

The antiderivative is : $n=\frac{a\sqrt{\pi c}}{2}\text{erf}(\frac{X-b}{\sqrt c})+constant$ 
$$n=\frac{a\sqrt{\pi c}}{2}\text{erf}(\frac{e^x-b}{\sqrt c})+constant$$